# PHP + curl catch POST response

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm working on a PHP + curl script to make payments (NOT TO RECEIVE) via the famous PP payment gw.

I'm able to fill a cart on an external website (not mine) and login for the payment (express checkout). After the login, I see the button "continue", which submits a POST form.

I'm able to send the requested parameters but I'm not able to retrieve the callback url contained into the response, so I just can't go there. I think I'm missing 2 parameters generated perhaps by a js: fso and fsi.

I followed the manual procedure (Firebug / NET panel / POST data) and I can confirm that the callback url is there. Following the last part of my code, thanks for any help.

```
#CURL SETUP
$session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1 );

#MY CURL OPERATION
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true ); //needed for 302
$output = curl_exec($session);
print_r($output);
```

I tried to get inspiration searchin around and from premade PHP classes, but all websites talk about receiving payments, not making payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself

ON CURL setup:

```
//suppress 100 continue curl bug
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') );
```

AFTER curl_exec

```
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$redirs = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT);
```

LET'S PRINT OUT THE RESULTS

```
echo "LAST URL<br><pre>".$lastUrl."</pre>";
echo "NUMBER OF REDIRS<br><pre>".$output."</pre>";
echo "LAST URL<br><pre>".$output."</pre>";
die();
```

every header will contain all the curl passages and please keep in mind that the steps you see into any debugger (safari web inspector, firebug, etc etc) e.g.

```
- 302 Found
- 302 Moved Temporarily
```

represent 1 single redirection. I hope it's useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to return the value (response) of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it out directly:

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
```

Comment: Of course, or else how could I have done the debug, print_r, preg_match, etc? CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER was set at the curl beginning, I integrated my question to avoid any misunderstandings.

Comment: You can't leave a bit of code out that's required to make it work and then say "Of course"... You'll need to give more information. what fields does the form send? What are you currently getting back?

Comment: sure, here's the code. i didn't mean to hurt you, sorry and thanks for the help.

I send POST request like this:
https://www.pxxpal.com/en/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?dispatch=0123blabla

I get the login page in my $output, but not the full json response, as I can see from firebug:
while (1); { "_type": "Rapids::PPAJAxxxowResponseVO", "html": "<img height=\"1\" width=\"1\" src=\"https: BLA BLA BLA

Comment: after some debug, I updated the question with other details. I hope they could be useful to get a reply or at least some inspiration.